# Twitter bootstrap media queries breakpoints

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I saw that twitter bootstrap 3 uses some classes like (hidden-xs, hidden-sm, hidden-md, hidden-lg) to hide or to show a block on some specific devices.

```
xs (extra small) -Phones - [0, 768px)
sm (small) -Tablets - [768px, 992px]
md (medium) -Desktops- [993px, 1200px]
lg (large) -Desktops- [1201px, infinite)
```

The thing i don't understand is why phones are considered to be up to 768px ? Because my ipad has 768px width and because of this is included into the phones category and automaticaly the design is the one displayed on the phone (witch is not right).

It's not more normal to be like this ?

```
xs (extra small) -Phones - [0, 480px)
sm (small) -Tablets - [481px, 768px]
md (medium) -Desktops- [769px, 992px]
lg (large) -Desktops- [993px, infinite)
```

In this way the phones will go up to 480px and after that, tables and desktops.

1. `What is the best configuration to use ?`
2. `If i change the media queries breakpoints into the ones i've specified, i should change the layout and grid system variables also ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), extra small devices are for less than 768px (up to 767px), and small devices are greater than or equal to 768px. These values seem to be exactly where they need to be and I would use them. Check out this [list of displays by pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density) and I think you'll see most devices fall within the pixel width of their respective Bootstrap group.